# codeblock prompts "the application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)", when I use IMG_load() function

Tags: c, sdl-2

I placed the image to be loaded in different suitable directories and checked.. Mine system is 64 bit, window8.1 and codeblock 17.12. What could be cause and solution for it?

Comment: Post the code along with the question statement which is causing this error to occur.

Comment: Thansks, Waleed Iqbal It's solved now after a struggle of two days and a minor change at the end.

Answer (score 0):

It was an issue not due to any problem in code but I was using 32bit codeblck and SDL_image.dll file of 64bit system. That was main reason and also some other .dll files relevant to SDL_image.h were missing that were not reason for this prompt appearing but impacts a bit in other way.